# How do I format roxygen2 return list similar to parameter list?

Tags: roxygen2

I've noticed that using `\describe{}` to create a list of returned objects does not have the same formatting as I see in documentation for packages I've downloaded from CRAN. How do I mimic their style? See the images below for the comparison. The code I used the generate the first is:

```
#' @return A list containing:\describe{
#'    \item{pars}{A numeric vector of parameter estimates}
#'    \item{std.errs}{A numeric vector of standard errors on parameters}
#'    \item{cov.mat}{Parameter covariance matrix (excluding mean)}
#' }
```

[image: My cruddy documentation][image: Gorgeous fancy documentation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to use the tabular environment, code text formatting, and additional lines. The below code works.

```
#' @return A list containing:\tabular{ll}{
#'    \code{pars} \tab A numeric vector of parameter estimates \cr
#'    \tab \cr
#'    \code{std.errs} \tab A numeric vector of standard errors on parameters \cr
#'    \tab \cr
#'    \code{cov.mat} \tab Parameter covariance matrix (excluding mean) \cr
#' }
```

[image]